# How can I conditionally set tabs in createBottomTabNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a static data file (json) that stores information like facebook page link. If the facebook page link is empty, I do NOT want the Follow Us tab to show. The facebook page link is stored in **businessDataJSON.facebook**. Is there a way to only show the Follow Us Tab if **businessDataJSON.facebook** is not empty (empty string)? This is my App.js:

```
const ListStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ListCategories: ListCategoriesScreen,
    ListCategoryItems: ListCategoryItemsScreen
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "ListCategories",
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: businessDataJSON.theme.navigationBarBackground
      },
      headerTintColor: businessDataJSON.theme.navigationBarTint,
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: "bold"
      }
    }
  }
);

const FollowUsStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    FollowUs: FollowUsScreen
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "FollowUs",
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: businessDataJSON.theme.navigationBarBackground
      },
      headerTintColor: businessDataJSON.theme.navigationBarTint,
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: "bold"
      }
    }
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(
  createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
      ListTab: {
        screen: ListStack,
        navigationOptions: {
          title: businessDataJSON.theme.tabBarListTitle,
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Icon
              name={businessDataJSON.theme.tabBarListIcon}
              size={17}
              color={tintColor}
            />
          )
        }
      },
      FollowUsStack: {
        screen: FollowUsStack,
        navigationOptions: {
          title: "Follow Us",
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Icon name="users" size={17} color={tintColor} />
          )
        }
      }
    },
    {
      tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: businessDataJSON.theme.tabBarIconActive,
        inactiveTintColor: businessDataJSON.theme.tabBarIconInactive,
        style: {
          elevation: 8,
          ...Platform.select({
            ios: { paddingTop: 4, paddingBottom: 4 },
            android: {
              borderTopWidth: 0,
              paddingTop: 6,
              paddingBottom: 6
            }
          })
        }
      }
    }
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you would need to make the creation of the tabs dinamic wich leads to the navigation prop to be lost and make a nightmare to use it without redux. The simple approach that i can see is to use a root createSwitchNavigator with a loading screen/start screen  and the tabs as the 2nd screen. in the loading screen you check if there is your facebook page, and navigate to them accordingly. this [example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html) is for auth, but it works in your case . trust me, the navigation props is a nightmare to manage.